# Autodesk Forge - View Draped image on C3D TIN surface

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Anyone as a guidance on how to see a draped image on a TIN surface using Autodesk Forge Viewer (today APS)?

Thanks

Comment: are you using Civil 3D files (DWG)?

Comment: yes, C3D dwg file, uploaded to BIM360. From there, loaded into Forge. In C3D I see the draped image over the TIN surface using realistic view in C3D. In Forge Viewer no image.

Comment: is the image embedded or is it a linked/xref file?

Comment: is a xref image. Could not drape an embedded image on C3D. Is it possible?

Comment: xref: when uploading for translation, it may help if you upload as a ZIP and set the rootFilename as the DWG.